# create-react-app-typescript failed with Proxy Authentication required error while creating app

Tags: create-react-app

I am working in corporate premise. I am trying to create react app with typescript but it failed with below error:

*D:\learning\reactjs>create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts*

*Creating a new React app in D:\learning\reactjs\my-app.*

*Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.*
*Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripemphasized textts-ts...*

*npm ERR! code E407*
***npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required: react-scripts-ts@latest***

*npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kalpanap\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-02-21T02_33_17_410Z-debug.log*

*Aborting installation.*
  *npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-**scripts-ts has failed.*

*Deleting generated file... package.json*
*Deleting my-app / from D:\learning\reactjs*

Can anyone help to fix this problem? 
Even I have updated npm config proxy and https-proxy to office n/w proxy. After this change only I was able to successfully run the npm install command.

How can I create-react-app with passing proxy parameters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your company's proxy must be not allowing you to access the setup.
Use the following two commands from command-promt

npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

In place of "proxy.company.com", use your proxy address that you are using.

You can find your proxy at 
IE Browser -> Internet Options -> Connections tab -> LAN Settings.